# Programmatically copy files between servers: scp or mount?

Tags: linux, language-agnostic

I run a process that generates some files on a server and want to copy them to another server. The two servers are on the same network.

What are the pros/cons of using scp or a network share?

I'm not talking about a one-time copy (which I'd do manually with scp), but about programmatically copying the files after they are generated.

Comment: `scp` can be scripted/automated just fine. I like the explicit connections/transfers. Now, if I was just "browsing"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rsync is a third possibility, and very easily scriptable. like scp, it uses ssh by default, and if you have already set up key-based authentication, it doesn't get any easier: `rsync -avuz /local/dir/ my.example.com:/remote/dir/`

some advantages over scp are the `--dry-run` and `--delete` options; the first is self-explanatory, the second deletes anything in the target that's not in the source.

network shares work great when they work, but when they break it can be a major hassle.

as pst said, scp can also be easily scripted, so if you have to choose between the two options you gave, I'd say go with scp simply because it's more reliable and just as easily scripted as copying from a network share.